# adding a close button to a html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a html5 video on our wordpress site and I would like to add a close button to it which will stop the video playback & remove/hide the video.

I was thinking that I could add an image to the page of a close button & with javascript to stop and hide the video on click.  Although I'm not sure how I could position this image of a close button correctly on the top right hand corner of the video?

Is there a better approach?

```
<video id="hp-video-player" controls="controls" preload="auto" loop="true">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="sample.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="sample.webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to throw the video as well as the container in a container like this:

```
<div id="video-container">
    <video id="hp-video-player" controls="controls" preload="auto" loop="true">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="sample.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="sample.webm">
    </video> 
  <!--  Controls -->
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop">Stop-Hide</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you just need to add the javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
          // Video
          var video = document.getElementById("video");  
          // Buttons
          var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
          var stopHideButton = document.getElementById("stop");
          //Now that that stuff is setup, you can script the functions for the buttons
          playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (video.paused == true) {
                video.play(); // Play video and change play button text to 'pause'
                playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
            } else {
                video.pause(); //Pause the video and change text to 'play'
                playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
            }   
          });
                stopHideButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                video.pause();
        //Now you can remove it a few ways. One being setting the source to Null
                video.src="";
        //or two, remove the div containing the video completely
              video.parentNode.removeChild(video);

          });
        }
</script>
```

You can reference [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) for more info on HTLM5 video and audio.